# How to eliminate backslash in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, encode

I constructed my xml file with javascript and I show it correctly with an alert like this :

```
<Voitures>
   <voiture par1="4" par2="1" par3="0"/>
   <voiture par1="3" par2="0" par3="0"/>
</Voitures>
```

But the problem is  when I send it with ajax to a php file I obtain this result :

```
<Voitures>
   <voiture par1=\"4\" par2=\"1\" par3=\"0\"/>
   <voiture par1=\"3\" par2=\"0\" par3=\"0\"/>
</Voitures>
```

Thank you

Comment: You've probably got [magic_quotes](http://php.net/magic_quotes) enabled, meaning you're on an old/crappy/badly-configured PHP version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your PHP configuration has [magic quotes](https://www.php.net/magic_quotes) enabled, which is a deprecated setting that nobody should be using anymore.  It has been removed in PHP 5.4.  **Disable it now**, or you risk writing code that will behave incorrectly when you upgrade to PHP 5.4.

If that's not possible, use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) on the value prior to doing anything else with it.  **Only do this if you really cannot disable magic quotes.  Developing PHP software with magic quotes enabled is a very, very bad idea.**

---

If you're trying to write good code and be future-proof, put this as the top of every file, or some common include file that gets used everywhere:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    trigger_error("Magic quotes are enabled; please disable them.", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

This will make your application simply refuse to run if magic quotes are enabled.

If you have the option, ship a `.htaccess` file with your application that contains this:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

This will, if possible, disable magic quotes for your entire application when it is depolyed on Apache.  If the Apache configuration does not permit `php_flag` directives in `.htaccess` files then this will cause an HTTP 500 error, which is miles better than letting your application run with magic quotes enabled.

Comment: Will be? PHP 5.4 has already been released, and we can all rejoice that the language is now a little less crappy.

Comment: @sgroves Ah, I didn't notice.  I've been busy using programming languages that don't get in my way.  :S  Updated my answer to remove the "will be" verbiage.

Comment: It"s okay with stripslashes(), Thank you very much.

Comment: @SlimMils Don't let the easy way out trick you into thinking that it's the right way to proceed.  **Developing PHP software with magic quotes enabled is a very bad mistake.**  It will hinder the portability of your software and complicates your code while providing only easily-defeated protection against SQL injection.  There is no benefit to leaving magic quotes enabled, and there are many advantages to disabling them.